# I am updating the ViewModel using data binding, but the View is not getting updated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

If I update the ViewModel, the View that consumes this data should be updated automatically right? What am I missing?

This is the MainActivity class:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        binding.btnTap.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            display()
        })
    }

    private fun display() {
        binding.apply {
            binding.myName?.name = binding.input.text.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the activity_main.xml file to be updated:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="MyName"
            type="com.rajneel.mymemory.viewmodel.MyName" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="@{MyName.name}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Tap" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I tried updating the text of the TextView explicitly like this :

```kotlin
 private fun display() {
        binding.apply {
            binding.myName?.name = binding.input.text.toString()
            binding.txtValue.text = binding.myName?.name
        }
    }
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I don't see any view model created in your Activity code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to give this a try?

Make sure that your MyName class is implemented properly as a data class, and create an instance of it in your ViewModel.

```
data class MyName(var name: String = "")
```

ViewModel Setup: In your MainActivity, create an instance of the MyName class and set it as the MyName variable in the binding.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel() // Replace MyViewModel with your ViewModel class

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.myName = viewModel.myName

        binding.btnTap.setOnClickListener {
            display()
        }
    }

    private fun display() {
        binding.myName?.name = binding.input.text.toString()
    }
}
```

Good Luck.

---------- editied -----------

Yeah and it seems like you might be referring to Android's data binding and ViewModel setup. If you intend to associate a ViewModel with a binding variable and set the lifecycle owner, the correct syntax would be:

```
binding.viewModel = viewModel
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

These lines of code are used to connect your ViewModel to the layout using data binding and ensure that the UI updates according to the LiveData changes within the ViewModel, while also maintaining proper lifecycle management.

Comment: I forgot to add.....I have created the data class and added an instance of it to my MainActivity file, and set the variable of the binding object to that instance. But it is still not working. Should I try using a ViewModel?

Comment: Yeah I added some content please refer to that.